# ¿Cómo puedo implementar argumentos que puedan ir acompañado opcionalmente de su valor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Tengo que implementar el script de un cliente en Python donde se le pasarán una serie de argumentos. En uno de ellos, el argumento puede puede ir acompañado de un valor de forma opcional, es decir, si se le pasa ese parámetro con valor o no el script debe realizar la acción correspondiente en cada caso. Algo de este estilo:

```
--create_id [alias]    # Alias es una cadena identificativa opcional.
```

Por ahora tengo hecho esto, usando el módulo `argparse`:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Procesamos los comandos del cliente') 
parser.add_argument('--create_id', nargs='*', help='crear id')  
parser.add_argument('--search_id', help='buscar id')    
parser.add_argument('--delate_id', type=int, help='borrar id')  
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.create_id:

    print("Has escogido la opcion --create_id")

elif args.search_id:

    print("Has escogido la opcion --search_id")

elif args.delate_id:

    print("Has escogido la opcion --delate_id")
```

Si el argumento de `--create_id` se acompaña del valor correspondiente entra dentro del `if`, pero si no lo tiene no entra. ¿Cómo puedo arreglar esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `nargs="?"` junto al argumento [`const`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#const). Debes darle un valor a `const` que no cree conflictos con los posibles valores del parámetro, con esto basta con que compruebes el valor del argumento:

```
port argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Procesamos los comandos del cliente') 
parser.add_argument('--create_id', nargs='?', const=True, help='crear id')
parser.add_argument('--search_id', help='buscar id')    
parser.add_argument('--delate_id', type=int, help='borrar id')  
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.create_id:
    print("Has escogido la opcion --create_id")
    if args.create_id == True:
        print("El parámetro --create_id no ha recibido ningún valor.")
    else:
        print("El parámetro --create_id ha recibido <{}> como valor.".format(args.create_id))
```

**Ejemplos:**

> $ test --create_id StackOverflow
>   Has escogido la opcion --create_id
>   El parámetro --create_id ha recibido <StackOverflow> como valor.
>
> $ test --create_id
>   Has escogido la opcion --create_id
>   El parámetro --create_id no ha recibido ningún valor.
>
> $ test

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente. Gracias por la ayuda!